# Is git cli safe to be used with torsocks?

Tags: torsocks, git

Theoretically, how safe is it to "torsocks git clone/pull/push"? Git is not listed as one of the ["100% Safe" applications in the wiki](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/torsocks#Security), but considering it uses either ssh or HTTP(S) as its underlying protocol, I see no reason to assume it would not work as expected. Am I missing something?

By "safe" I mean "origin IP does not leak to server hosting the repository". The identity of the requester, for operations that involve authentication and authorization, will obviously be known.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is, has anyone done a thorough professional test of the git cli for leaks and the answer is probably no they haven't so you can't be 100% conclusively sure it is "safe".

Of course, Linus Torvalds himself wrote Git and so it is open source. The source code can always be honest and you can reach out to the Tor community via the mailing lists or IRC chat to see if anyone has any doubts about it.

As a side note. If you signed up to Github, Gitlab, etc. without Tor, they already know your IP so then the point is moot. The only way to be 100% sure is to run your own Gitlab or other git-based service. As a matter of fact, The Tor Project is moving to their own internal gitlab instance instead of the old source control platform.